# como hacer para que el position fixed siga manteniendo su espacio contenedor

Tags: css

al momento de poner `position: fixed` , el elemento se sale de su espacio contenedor cuando no debería y no quiero que se salga , solo quiero que quede fijo , pero que respete la posición de su espacio contenedor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando le pongo un left:0; no me funciona y se queda en el mismo sitio, pero cuando le pongo un right :0; sucede esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo quiero que quede en la izquierda en un position fixed como una ventana flotante pero que respete su espacio y no se junte con el otro contenedor

```
#contenedor de BORDER color AZUL
.contenedor-cuerpo-izquierda{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;


}

# CONTENEDOR DE BORDER DE COLOR VERDE
.contenedor-cuerpo-derecha{
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor la duda por favor?, no termino de entender el problema

Comment: claro, eh colocado un position fixed a la caja del borde de color azul , donde dice productos , pero al momento de color un fixed , pierde su posicion y se junta con el otro contenedor , y lo que no quiero esque se junten, yo quiero que el contenedor de al que puse fixed , siga manteniendo su posicion sin perderla pero con la opcion de fixed